# How to use an if statement to only collect forms fields that contain an '@' symbol in?

Tags: javascript, if-statement, nested-if

I'm currently collecting form abandonments from my website using the javascript code below within the tag manager of analytics software (Piwik pro).

It currently works great, however, I'm now trying to make it so that only emails with an '@' collect and nothing else.

I'm thinking that an if statement that has .includes("@") will do the job, however as I'm a beginner and I did not write this code, I am struggling to make it work. The below shows what I've tried (amongst many other attempts) and it either continues to collect everything or doesn't collect anything...

(Also I'm unsure if `_paq.push` is used outside of the analytics software I use, but that line creates a custom event within Piwik pro.)

```
formFields = ['input_3_1','input_3_2','input_3_3','input_3_4']

  let formFieldText = document.getElementById('input_3_1').value
  let fieldHasAtSymbol = formFieldText.includes("@")
  
  if (fieldHasAtSymbol = 'true') {

        function trackUnsubmittedField(fieldId){
          let formField = document.getElementById(fieldId)
          if(formField.nodeName==="SELECT"){
            formField.addEventListener('change',()=>{
              _paq.push(['trackEvent','formAbandonment',fieldId,document.getElementById(fieldId).value])
            })
          }
          else{
            formField.addEventListener('focusout',()=>{
                _paq.push(['trackEvent','formAbandonment',fieldId,document.getElementById(fieldId).value])
            })
          }
        }
  }
        formFields.map(element=>trackUnsubmittedField(element))
```

I've also tried using the same form field variable that's declared within the function by placing a `.includes()` if statement within it, but no luck.

```
formFields = ['input_3_1','input_3_2','input_3_3','input_3_4']

        function trackUnsubmittedField(fieldId){
          let formField = document.getElementById(fieldId)
          
                if (formField.includes("@") = "true") {
          
          if(formField.nodeName==="SELECT"){
            formField.addEventListener('change',()=>{
              _paq.push(['trackEvent','formAbandonment',fieldId,document.getElementById(fieldId).value])
            })
          }
          else{
            formField.addEventListener('focusout',()=>{
                _paq.push(['trackEvent','formAbandonment',fieldId,document.getElementById(fieldId).value])
            })
                }
        }
  
        formFields.map(element=>trackUnsubmittedField(element))
```

There's probably a lot wrong with the code I added onto this but any help would be appreciated.

Comment: `if (formField.includes("@")) { ... }` - it's enough, `.includes()` returns boolean, so can be used as `if` condition without any comparing

Comment: conditionally creating a function makes no sense. You should not declare a function within an `if` statement.

Comment: `if (fieldHasAtSymbol = 'true') {` is a mistake and should be `if (fieldHasAtSymbol == true) {` or simply `if (fieldHasAtSymbol) {`. The `if (formField.includes("@") = "true") {` in your snippet should actually throw an exception with an error message telling that it is wrong. Otherwise, the second approach looks just fine.